# Can I invoke two web service with one input and i want to display two output in BPEL eclipse?

Tags: web-services

Can I invoke two web service with one input and I want to display output separately from each web service in BPEL eclipse?

Comment: I think you might need a little more information here.

Comment: do you have suggestion ? do you need any input from me ? I have two web service, one is a+b and a*b, i want to show a+b and a*b